# SQL Swapped values between columns

Tags: sql, vertica

Due to import error I have this weird situation.

Suppose a table:

```
date         feat1   feat2
2019-01-01      a      z
2019-01-01      a      z
2019-01-03      z      a
2019-01-04      z      a
2019-01-05      z      a
```

From a certian date , we have values from `feat1` and column `feat2` swapped. 
Result I'm looking for

```
date         feat1   feat2
2019-01-01      a      z
2019-01-01      a      z
2019-01-03      a      z
2019-01-04      a      z
2019-01-05      a      z
```

How can I fix this in one update statement without creating a temp column? I'm using Vertica DB

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work in TSQL, you can use it as a base:

```
UPDATE tbl SET feat1 = feat2, feat2 = feat1 WHERE date >= 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Comment: That should work in any self-respecting database system.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this?

```
update t
    set feat1 = t1.feat1,
        feat2 = t1.feat2
    from (select t.*
          from t
          order by t.date
          limit 1
         ) t1
    where t.feat1 <> t1.feat1 or t1.feat2 <> t1.feat2;
```

This does not require knowing the "magic date" or the specific values.  If the values can be `NULL`, you would want to take that into account with the comparison logic.

If you just wanted a `select` query, the `first_value()` does what you want:

```
select t.date,
       first_value(t.feat1) over (order by t.date) as feat1,
       first_value(t.feat2) over (order by t.date) as feat1
from t;
```